# Fix Double Eclipse Menubar

Tags: eclipse, menubar

Im not even sure exactly what to call this, but how do I fix it? Obviously I only need one place for these options in the Eclipse menubar. It doesnt duplicate the whole thing, just this section. If I remove all of the language options (Java, Debug, C++) it will go away, but I need to be able to switch views. Suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Window** → **Customize Perspective** → **Menu Visibility**

There you should be able to *remove/add* menu items.

Comment: If I remove something there, both items disappear, and if I readd it they both come back.

Comment: If you have them both, I think there should be two checkboxes for each one of them. Look for them and uncheck the redundant.